# How to divide large numbers with a floating point?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, largenumber, arbitrary-precision

I have some large numbers (like **10000000** digits in total or **more**). Since I will lose precision, they are stored like ***strings***.
Lets take some 'small' numbers as an example (some numbers also can be integers):

```
a = 4782916578987656789087654678908765467417657489104.9486718490129876578
b = 657890876566567890.8765467890987654
```

I want to make some operations on them.

**Division**. Well, answer is `7.270075858095143e+30`

**Multiplicaiton:** `3.1466371806949598e+66`
And so on.

Desirable output is ***full number as string***, but with **given precision for floating point with trancated zeros and rest**.

Example:
 
`888888888888.23 / 2.5122217 == 353825814373.082590504959329565857965`
(24 digits after 'point')`

*I've tried* `decimals` module, but it can't handle big integers: `class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible` and maybe something else what I'm not aware of.

Is there is a way to do it with *standard* library, or at least `numpy`. Or maybe some algorithm what I can also reproduce in some other languages like JavaScript?

Note: I know I can make `Decimal.getcontext().prec = 8888888888888` or bigger, but it will took more time to calculate, and what if numbers are 1 and 1.7373 do I need to waste resources on it? Also it's precision for whole number, not only 'floating' digits.

Comment: There's a third-party module named [`mpmath`](https://pypi.org/project/mpmath/) — [home page](http://mpmath.org/) — that implements "arbitrary-precision floating-point arithmetic" which I think would allow you to do what you want.

Comment: What are you doing that requires numbers with 10 million digits of precision?

Comment: The number of atoms in the universe only requires 82 digits.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what precision are you looking for? 100 digits after the decimal point? 1000 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: @martineau great, thx, but something not 3rd-party would be better to understanding how it works, what is used. I'm not confident enough to dig into library source code :)

Comment: @Barmar just playing with stuff, wondering how it's possible to calcute and so on :)

Comment: @David well 50 would be enough, but you never know what you will need later. My curiosity are leading to these strange questions.

Comment: Call me Walter: I know you said that in your question, too, but I don't think it's possible (or practically-so) without a third-party library — and think `mpmath` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

The `decimal` module is your friend here. If you want to go wild, well...

```py
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal
import sys

c = decimal.getcontext()
c.prec = 899_999_768
c.Emax = decimal.MAX_EMAX
c.Emin = decimal.MIN_EMIN

a = Decimal('149846549e500000')
b = Decimal('254984984e449')

d = a / b
f = a * b
```

Remember that `c.prec` gives you the number of digits that are shown when you print it. According to the documentation, the maximum number is `999999999999999999`, and you are bound to the memory of your computer. In my case (my computer, actually), `c.prec` is a good number before the computer breaks.

If you print the results, what happens?

```py
print(f'{d}')
print(f'{f}')
```

Since you want to play with big, big numbers, well, there you have it.

P.S. I am trying to write a number with `10 000 000` digits, but my text editors don't allow that... they freeze.

Comment: "Remember that `c.prec` gives you the number of digits after the decimal point." Well, for me it's 'total' numbers. If I set `c.prec = 2` and then divide 13 by 3, I will recieve `4.3` not `4.33`. That is one of the reasons why I ask.